# pychromecast api connect to chromecast

Tags: python, api, chromecast

I am trying to connect with the pychromecast API to my Chromecast for some home project that I make. To connect to the Chromecast I assisted with the "how to use" from the api repo on github. the problem is when I need to print the status I get the next error :

```
 AttributeError: 'Chromecast' object has no attribute 'status'
```

and the next part of the code influenced from this.
I would appreciate any help ! Thanks.

code -

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pychromecast

cast = pychromecast.get_chromecast(friendly_name="Chromecast")
#print(cast.device)
print(cast.status)

mc = cast.media_controller
mc.play_media('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4', 'video/mp4')
print(mc.status)

mc.pause()
time.sleep(5)
mc.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your installation is not proper possibly because of the version of dependencies such as the package of zerconf and netifaces. Have a look at those steps to deep into because he had exactly the same problem and it was resolved. 
http://www.ozturkibrahim.com/playing-with-google-chromecast/